# Run php script through command line

Tags: php, command-line

I want to run my `php code` through command line.

Is it possible? Can any one tell me ?

Comment: Yes why not. You can do: `php -f script.php` from a shell

Comment: see:: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: -1 Googling "PHP Command Line" brings you here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Make sure you have installed `php_cli` on your machine,
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php